# What are the exact requirements for tag badges?

Tags: support, tags, badges

If you look at the description of the requirements for tag badges, it is actually pretty vague.

For example, the silver badge requires a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers.

Is it really this simple, or are there hidden provisions?  For instance, do answers with scores of zero or less count?  Do answers on your own questions count?

If it makes any difference, I am asking because I want to know how close I am to getting my silver LotR badge.  As such, it would be great if someone could tell me what, if anything, I still have to do before I get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered on the main meta site here;

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395)

To answer your specific points;

- No, answers that are at zero still count toward the total.
- Yes, answers to your own questions do count.

---

### Badge progress.

You presently have **81** answers to [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) tagged questions.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a44025%20%5blord-of-the-rings%5d%20is%3aanswer

However, at least 4 are [community wiki answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44025+%5Blord-of-the-rings%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ano) so you're *just* bubbling under at present.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not seeing the part about only upvoted answers being counted- the only mention of votes is this:  "A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). As well, posts which are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score. Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC."

Comment: @WadCheber - I've conferred with some other mods and I've amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY!

Comment: How do I find out how many of my answers are CW?  Also, how many questions can I ask you before you start to hate me?

Comment: @WadCheber Use the search function: [`user:44025 [lord-of-the-rings] is:answer wiki:no`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44025+[lord-of-the-rings]+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ano).

Comment: @TARS - Cheers. Much appreciated.

Comment: @WadCheber - 4 of them are CW which puts you back under the line.

Comment: @TARS - GODDAMITALL.  4 CW answers...  I'm going to go and throw myself off a bridge.  See you later.

Comment: @Richard - I can't argue with most of the 4 answers being made CW, but one only has 7 revisions (as opposed to anywhere from 11 to 26 on the others).  I'm going to contest that one, but I think the others should stay CW.

Comment: @WadCheber So uhh, don't check the 'make CW' box next time?  Flag anything you don't want CW'ed, and a mod can fix it.

Comment: @Keen - I have never intentionally made an answer CW.  I had assumed that it happened automatically.  Apparently that doesn't happen anymore, so I guess I accidentally checked the box on those answers.  That is kind of strange, though, because all my CW answers have a ton of revisions.

Comment: @WadCheber The site *used* to convert posts after they were edited a certain number of times, but 7 revisions is below that threshold.  Only way it could have happened at that point is if you or a mod checked that box.